# Can't make anything other than folder in C:\ Windows 8

Tags: windows-8

Since Windows XP I could make any type of file I wanted in C:. I could right click, and make a text file that I could create logs with, etc.

Now, in windows 8 though, I can't make anything in C:\ other than a folder. I assume it's because of my privileges. I need to be able to make files in C:\ on demand.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you logged on as admin?

Comment: @Anteara - This is by design.  Of course you also can force it by approving the creating of the file or folder.  The correct location for temp files is NOT the C directory.

Comment: @Anteara - WHY do you need to make files in the C:\ folder on demand from Explorer using right-click?  Windows (like any OS) **strongly discourages** you from doing this!

Answer (score 2):

You get the same issue with Windows 7 as well.

You have to do Start, type cmd, (to search it out), then don't hit ENTER yet, and when the cmd prompt  appears in the start menu, right click it, do runas administrator

Comment: FYI, it's been ages but in case you didn't know this by now in older versions of windows you hit [Windows Key]-[r] to open "Run" and then type cmd (or whatever) and if you hit [CTRL]+[ENTER] instead of just enter it will open it with Admin rights. I thought this didn't work in Windows 10, but it still does, you just strangely have to do it from the search bar in the start menu instead of in run. Why it doesn't work in both (or at least Run still) is beyond me but .. thank god I found out how to do it at all. Life saver.

Comment: @BrentRittenhouse good to know, though 2019 and I still use W7!

Answer (score 2):

1. Open **This Pc**
2. Right Click On **Local Disk C:**
3. Click on **Properties**
4. Select the **Security** tab

[image: Step 4 and 5]

5. Click on **Advanced**
6. You may add your windows username by clicking on **Add** or select the **[YourComputer]>\Administrators** and Click **Edit**

[image: Step 6]

7. Click On **Show Advanced Permissions** at the right corner of the form
8. Check **Full Control** and Press **OK** and close all windows.

[image: full control, permissions list]

Now you may create any type of file on drive C, I don't recommend to alter *Windows 10* default security settings unless you have some program that does not work anymore because of this resitriction,Cause some program create temporary file(s) on drive C root and they need full control on root folder to run.

[image: result of right click]

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are in the admin group.  If you aren't a computer administrator, writting to C isn't allowed by default.
The files you should have full read write on are in 
`C:\Users\yourname\`

Maybe you could do your work in there? Other wise, get elevated privileges from your network admins.

Comment: You also need to elevate your request, just being a member of the local administrators group alone isn't enough. That said, I agree 100% with you that it's a great idea to try to keep non-OS non-program files under the user folder. For one thing it makes it much easier to index them for searching, and to back them up. Here's more information on elevation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run_as_administrator

Comment: @MarkAllen - Okay, well I'll do my work on C:\ in the user folder. However, I don't see the problem with operating in the root folder of B:\, D:\, and E:\. These are all different hard drives, none of them contain vital OS data. Yet even so, I can't create any files here other than folders. I want a way to do it simply by right clicking and pressing new, no elevation, no nothing - I want it just like it was in Windows XP, Vista, and 7. 
Again to reiterate, there is no reason THIS should be frowned upon given that NONE of the hard drives contain vital OS data.

Comment: The idea behind making it other-than-simple is that something managing to run as you can't just go and run amok on your computer. Blame all those viruses and email worms of the late 1990s, plus the fact that other OSes have had this kind of security for a long time. XP was definitely easier.

Comment: @Anteara The reason is probably that people may put C:\ in the path, and then things written there get executed.  Make a directory like C:\a or C:\blah and do things there. Then it's easy to get to.

Comment: @MarkAllen but then it's not so easy to get to, c:\users\blahuser\documents   that isn't that convenient. it's not as bad as "c:\documents and settings"  but it's still a bit longwinded.. easier if c:\blah or c:\a.   I wouldn't put vital data in c:\users because if you delete your OS, you'd have to be sure from trying removing that windows before, that the users directory isn't going to go. Whereas if you put it in c:\blah and remove your OS, you KNOW c:\blah won't go.

Answer (score -1):

Go to C: drive properties and click on the *Security* tab. There, select your user and provide full access.

Comment: This is a [shoe or bottle question](http://weblogs.asp.net/alex_papadimoulis/archive/2005/05/25/408925.aspx). While your answer is technically correct, the better thing to do is teach the correct way to do something than trying to shoehorn in the OP's method in to a working way.

Comment: +1  Very interesting.. technically correct it seems, and also showed me something I didn't know(though you did Scott)  http://i.imgur.com/8e2bp8A.png  that pic explains a lot.  @ScottChamberlain The correct way is to not hide that truth, but to write that truth, AND to say the way to do it and not to do it(like, to not provide full access to "users"). But i'm glad what he said was mentioned, 'cos as you say, it is technically correct.  That counts for a lot. He should have said not typically recommended or generally ever recommended.

Comment: Now I can create a folder and a sub folder in that folder without any annoying popups. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

You can turn off UAC if needed.

Press keys <kbd>Windows Key</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, type:

```
regedit
```

Locate:
    HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\EnableLUA

Update the EnableLUA value to 0 (turn if off)

Restart Windows.

This disables UAC entirely and allows write to c:\ as a result.

Comment: This also disables Windows Store applications.  This also was already suggested by a previous [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/505554/cant-make-anything-other-than-folder-in-c-windows-8/857262#857262)

Answer (score -3):

```
Press keys “Windows Key + R”, type regedit
Locate HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\EnableLUA
Update the EnableLUA value to 0 (turn if off)
Restart Windows.
```

Comment: People are (and should be), hesitant to muck around making manual changes to the registry, especially when there are other answers that don't require that.  Also, as a brand new user, you don't yet have any reputation on the site so people may be wary of trusting a potentially risky suggestion from you.  Can you expand your answer a little?  Explain what this setting does.  Perhaps cite a reference that people can check to verify for themselves that the information is correct.

Comment: This effectively disables the prompt for UAC. Do you have any evidence that this might actually fix the problem?